# How to configure output folder for ejb stubs in RSA "prepare for deployment"

Tags: eclipse, svn, websphere, code-generation

I would like to configure the output folder for the generated EJB stubs for WAS 7.0 when doing a "prepare for deployment" in RSA 8.0.

Currently the sources of the generated stubs are generated to the normal source folder of the eclipse project. Because of that generated and manually edited code is mixed. That's why I can't easily create SVN ignores for these generated files. So I would like that these files are generated to another source folder `ejbmodule-gen` instead of the `ejbmodule` source folder that contains the manually edited sources.

In the preferences I'm able to set the `output folder` of an `EJB Project` under `Java EE -> Project`. However this does not have an effect.

I could also use some more elaborate patterns for SVN ignores. But I don't want to mess around with them as they are already repeated much too often in build files and other places in the project.

So how can I make sure that selecting `Java EE -> Prepare for Deployment` will put generated source files to another folder than the original source folder of the project?

Comment: I understand that it is about EJB version 2.X, isn't it?

Comment: @trikelef actually it is both, ejb 3.0 and ejb 2.1. But a solution for ejb 2.1 is more important at the moment.

Comment: I am afraid that for EJB 2.1 the following limitation holds: "Multiple output folders are not supported for EJB projects" based on "Limitations of EJB 1.x - 2.x development tools"(http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.j2ee.doc/topics/relimitcurrent.html).

Comment: @trikelef You should put that in an answer. this seems worth the bounty, if no one else comes up with a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that for **EJB 2.1** the following limitation holds on **Rational version 8.0**:

**[Multiple output folders are not supported for EJB projects](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.j2ee.doc/topics/relimitcurrent.html)**

However if there is enough flexibility in the project I would recommend to manually use the [createEJBStubs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.ejbfep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rejb_3stubscmd.html) Websphere command to generate the EJB stubs or (better) to use an [ANT](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21393419) (or whatever) build script to build the binaries per your preference.